# no permission to edit file?

Tags: 16.04, gpu

I'm trying to disable Vsync on my BARTS radeon card (source game stuck at 60 fps)

I was directed to the file `/usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf` to add Option "SwapBuffersWait" "false"
I'm finding I have no permission to edit the file? What gives?

[image: screenshot]

Any responses / wishes for luck appreciated. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Open the terminal and write `sudo nautilus` , after that you can open any file and edit with root rights.

Comment: Noooo. Never run `sudo nautilus`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `root` privileges to edit this file. Open it with sudo.

```
sudo nano /usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
```

now you can add option

```
SwapBuffersWait false
```

Save and close the file.

Comment: TYVM!!!!!!!!!!!